# ClassCastException cannot convert LinearLayout$LayoutParams to AbsListView$LayoutParams when setting ListView Header

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

First off, I've already figured out how to solve this bug, but at this point I'm just wondering why my fix works.  The situation I was running into was that I was getting a `ClassCastException, cannot convert LinearLayout$LayoutParams to AbsListView$LayoutParams` when I tried to do the following (simplified for these purposes):

```
mLayout = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater()
   .inflate(R.layout.my_header_layout, 
   getListView(), false);
mRootView.addView(mLayout);
getListView().addHeaderView(mLayout);
getListView().setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

I eventually broke it down and discovered that the issue was fixed when I removed the call to `mRootView.addView(mLayout)`

My two-fold question is, why is this happening?  First, on the conceptual side, why is it that when a header view is already in the layout the whole thing just dies?  Is it because that view is effectively trying to be laid out twice: once for the header and once for the actual layout?

Secondly, why this exception?  It seems awfully non-descriptive and it doesn't look like it captures the actual problem at all?  Is this a case of a high level issue not being handled because a lower level function will just fail on the results anyway?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you did not change anything else?

Comment: Mmm, it appears the night off made me foregetful, I've updated the question according to how I was able to repro and then fix this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is, why is this happening? First, on the conceptual side, why is it that when a header view is already in the layout the whole thing just dies? Is it because that view is effectively trying to be laid out twice: once for the header and once for the actual layout?

Your layout params are going crazy here, that's the problem.

- `inflate()` is called, assigning `ListView.LayoutParams` to `mLayout`, since you pass a ListView as the root. [From the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean%29):

> **root:** Optional view to be the parent of the generated hierarchy (if attachToRoot is true), or else simply an object that provides a set of LayoutParams values for root of the returned hierarchy (if attachToRoot is false.)

- When you use `addView()`, it [checks the type](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/LinearLayout.java#1218) of the child's params. If it doesn't match, it converts it as best it can. It does this by copying the values over in [a new constructor](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/view/ViewGroup.java#5593). So, your `mLayout` now has `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` attached.
- Once you call `addHeaderView()`, `mLayout` is now a child of the listview. One of the things done during [`ListView#setupChild()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/ListView.java#1645) is this:

  `AbsListView.LayoutParams p = (AbsListView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();`

This is almost definitely where you're getting the ClassCastException. You just can't do a straight cast like that.

---

> Secondly, why this exception? It seems awfully non-descriptive and it doesn't look like it captures the actual problem at all?

It's not that bad, but you have to understand how the layout system works. Could they do a simple check, and just throw an error or log message if it's not right? Sure. Could `ListView` try to gracefully handle the issue the way a `LinearLayout` does? Sure. But they don't.

It might be worth posting on the Android Developer's forum/group/tracker if you think it could be handled better.

Answer (score 0):

It all lies in the statement:

> ```
> cannot convert LinearLayout$LayoutParams to AbsListView$LayoutParams
> ```

`LinearLayout` and `AbsoluteListView` have 2 different types of layouts, so you would need to setup the `LayoutParams` by using the following:

```
mLayout.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

because now you are using `AbsListView`-specific `LayoutParams`.