# ExpandableListView.addHeaderView() did not retain layout parameter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, expandablelistview

I have a RelativeLayouts that I want to add as a header to an ExpandableList. Basically, the layout is the same as the one I used for the child views in the list.

Here's the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="50dp"
    android:paddingStart="50dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Electricity"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/current_balance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="Rp 300.000"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/current_budget"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Rp800.000"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/current_expenses"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Rp800.000"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then I add the header inside onCreateView as follows:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_budget_list, container, false);

View listHeader = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_budget_item, null);
// populate views in the header

ExpandableListView listView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_budget);
listView.addHeaderView(listHeader);
listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

The header was shown, however, it looks like the height was changed to 0, because the TextViews in the 1st line (category_name and current_balance) were overlapping with the 2nd line (current_budget and current_expenses).

(note: the layout was shown correctly when used as list's child view )

Is this because the layout was convert to AbsListView? 
How can I retain the layout parameters?
I've tried `listHeader.setMinimumHeight()` but it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17953879/4666879)

Apparently when inflating the header layout, I need to provide the `ExpandableListView` as the root and `false` to `attachToRoot`. Therefore, the layout params value will be provided to the root view. So the code looks like this:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_budget_list, container, false);
ExpandableListView listView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_budget);

View listHeader = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_budget_item, listView, false);
```

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean%29):

> **root**: Optional view to be the parent of the generated hierarchy (if attachToRoot is true), or else simply an object that provides a
>   set of LayoutParams values for root of the returned hierarchy (if
>   attachToRoot is false.)

Answer (score 0):

I do not see listview in your layout.
if you want a header in your list, i suggesting you to add it like this:

```
 <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/activity_chat_listView"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in onCreate add `mListView.setAdapter(mChatAdapter);`  where `private ChatAdapter mChatAdapter;` 
I assume that this layout you provide , will load many times through `Loader<Cursor>`
Now, in ChatAdapter bindView or GetView you will decide whenever you want this header to be visible or gone.

there are a lot of good examples for Cursor adapter to see.
check one here https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters/
it depends on your needs.
hope it helps